# How to add a title to an asp:ListItem from frontend?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like to get titles on my radio button list items. How is this achieved?

EXAMPLE :

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem title="Temporary">Temp.</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem title="Permanent">Perm.</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: You would like to get titles where / on what (user) action?

Comment: when user hovers over the radio button they should see whats inside the title tag appear over the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `Tooltip`.

Take a look at this MS example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tooltip?view=netframework-4.8

Or, if you use Bootstrap in your project, take a look at Bootstrap's tooltip:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/